# Scrape all tables using python while some of them should be clicked at first

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, python-requests

I need to scrape all tables from 2014-2021 under this website: https://csrbox.org/India-list-CSR-projects-India, and you can see that even though I click the button 2019-20, the url doesn't change and everytime I click next page it will return to the 2020-21 automatically.

I tried with these codes:

```
htmls = []
url = 'https://csrbox.org/India-list-CSR-projects-India?page={idx}'
for idx in range(1, 135):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("**scraping: page%d" % idx)
    r = requests.get(url.format(idx=idx))
    htmls.append(r.text)
htmls[1]
df = pd.read_html(htmls[1])
df_list = []
for html in htmls:
    df = pd.read_html(html)
    df_list.append(df[0])
    
df_all = pd.concat(df_list)

df_all.head(3)    
df_all.shape    

df_all[["Project Name", "Name of the Company", "Thematic Area", "Project Budget", "Location"]].to_excel("csr_data.xlsx", index=False)
```

They work for the first part 2020-21, but for the remaing years there are nothing in the sheet, and I also tried these codes to realize the 'click':

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('2019-20').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

It indeed can be realized to to turn to the table of 2019-20, but since then I don't know how to merge these two parts of codes. Or can I realize the 'click' with requests?  I'm sorry if this question is stupid because I'm new to python and for me it's quite complicated...

Answer (score 0):

When information is loaded by javascript, like on the page you linked, you need to use the webbrowser's console to see what is happening behind the scenes.

These instructions are for Firefox, but other webbrowsers should be similar.

Press `F12` with the page open, and go to the "Network" tab.  Then click the button that loads the data you're interested in.

You should see a request pop up in the console:

[image]

You can see it is a `POST` request to `ajaxdata.php`, so let's see what data we're sending in the request:

Click on the request, and select the "Request" tab:

[image]

You can see we're sending two important values, `page`, and `tab`.  Once you know the values for the other tables, it should be relatively simple to write a python Post Request to get the relevant data.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for answer but I still can't get the tables I want. I added these codes: 'payload= {'tab':'2015-16'}' and 'r = requests.post(url.format(idx=idx),params=payload)' and it still showed tables from 2020-21.

Comment: I found the solution and thanks again for your hint! It really helped me a lot. :)